# Order by record count on sub collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to convert some old code to use Fluent Nhibernate.

Old code:

```
allOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrdersLineItems.Count);
```

How do I convert it to something like:

```
query.AddOrder(new Order(????, true));
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Here is the simplified code I am trying to write:

```
ICriteria query = FluentSessionManager.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Orders>()
     .AddOrder(new Order(????, true));
```

The joined table is OrdersLineItems.  I need to set the order by the count of the line items.  Since I am using paging with a data set that has over 500,000 records, simply pulling all the records into memory and then sorting them will not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6845746/671619 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/253999/671619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ICriteria query = FluentSessionManager.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Orders>()
   .CreateAlias("this.OrderLineItems", "oli")
   .AddOrder(new Order(Projections.Count("oli.Id"), true));
```

Something like that I should think. It's probably not perfect but at least illustrates that you need to use Projections.Count to get it done.

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thank you so very much.